# Use symlinks to remove .php extension -> raw .php file gets served

Tags: php, linux, apache, symlink, friendly-url

I have created a symlink (using ln -s index.php test) to my index.php to try and get a 'prettier' url without the .php extension.
However, when I access https://myservername.com/test I get served the raw php file instead of the interpreted content.

I would like to avoid having to turn on mod_rewrite if possible since it will be for this one file only (I am using the CodeIgniter framework that does the url translation for the rest of the files).

Is there a way for apache to read the real destination file instead of the symlink to determine that it is a php script?  Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Yes, the better way of accomplishing it is to use the proper tool (which in this case is `mod_rewrite`)...

Comment: Ok, adding the following to my <Directory> section in httpd.conf did the trick (I renamed the index.php to ci.php):<br>RewriteEngine on<br>
    RewriteRule ^test$ /test/ [R]<br>
    RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ ci.php/$1 [L]

Comment: Well, replace the above <br> tags with actual carriage returns.

Comment: @ircmaxell: the proper tool is Alias... the swiss kniffe can do a lot of things but sometimes the KISS rule apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want mod_rewrite (I think it is legimate, in the past security issue of mode_reqrite has occurs, if you do not need it why using it?):

```
Alias /index /var/ww/mydocumentroot/index.php
```

Alias is provided by mod_alias that you should have. *Remove you symlink*.

Comment: Perfect, thank you:  this is what I was looking for.  I figured since I only needed it for one file, that mod_rewrite was overkill (although I see lots of uses for it in other projects).

Answer (score 3):

I bet the problem is that Apache is only calling the PHP interpreter on files with a `.php` extension, and since your symlinks have no extension whatsoever they aren't interpreted.

Try using mod_rewrite instead, or try messing around with Apache directives, like [FollowSymLinks](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html) - not sure if it applies here though. You don't want to enable the PHP parser for all files, that's for sure.

Comment: Yeah, I had already turned on FollowSymLinks, but I agree that turning on the PHP parser for everything is a bad idea.  I decided to bite the bullet and learn how to use mod_rewrite:  I'm just as glad I did though as it looks to be an incredibly useful tool.